# How can i place the Highcharts yAxis categories inside the chart?

Tags: highcharts

I want to move the categories on my Y Axis inside the chart, like the new Google Analytics does.

See image:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1)You can use the labels.align property.
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/labels-align-left/

2)Use the labels.x property
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-x/